# dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract in magento

Tags: database, magento, model, resources

When I tried to create a custom module and get this error.

I just change the permission of `etc/local.xml` to 644 to 646 it error comes
after it I back it to 644 but it seems to same error. Many Forums discussed this issue but unfortunately, I don't get any results.

I cleared `cache`, `reindexed`. What else should I do to solve this one.

`var` folder permission is setuped 777. Even I tried in fresh Magento installation but same error.

> a:5:{i:0;s:65:"dbModel read resource does not implement
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:4193:"#0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_moip/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(NULL)
>
> 1
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_moip/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Cis_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders))
>
> 2
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_moip/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('recurringorders...',
>   Object(Cis_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders))
>
> 3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_moip/app/Mage.php(490):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('recurringorders...',
>   Object(Cis_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders))
>
> 4
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_moip/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208):
>   Mage::getResourceModel('recurringorders...',
>   Object(Cis_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders))

Answer (score -1):

This problem may also arrived when you extend wrong class in:

```
class Companyname_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    { 
        $this->_init('recurringorders/recurringorders', 'id_recurringorders');
    }
}
```

Below is Correct Code:

```
class Companyname_Recurringorders_Model_Mysql4_Recurringorders extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('recurringorders/recurringorders', 'id_recurringorders');
    }
}
```

This solved the issue.